# Call the results from a previous Foreach

Tags: php, foreach, woocommerce

I am trying to get the results from my Foreach in another echo way later then the foreach but I am stuck, any help would be much appericated.

```
$items = $order->get_items();

// Output the loop
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    // Getting some information
    $product_qty = $item['qty'];
$product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);

    // SKU
    $SKU = $product->get_sku();
    print_r($SKU); 
    print_r($product_qty); 
    print_r('&nbsp;');
}
// this gives all 3 quantities and all 3 sku, added a space at the end for easier reading

// this only gives the 1st entry of both variables but i need all 3 of both variables 
echo '<a href="https://www.domainname.someurl'.$product_quantity .$SKU . '" target=_blank>'; 

echo "<p>TEXT</p></a>";
```

I hope it is clear like this, thanks

Comment: I don't see `$product` defined when you use it to get the sku. Nor `$product_quantity` in the echo. You should be able to get all your values if they're in the `$item` array just fine.

Comment: try concatenate the values in foreach loop and use them later.

Comment: added the $product, the echo down there is just a hyperlink in progress, so far I am working on an join/implode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're overwriting the value of $SKU and product_qty on each iteration, maybe try storing them in an array? Like create an array outsite the loop and use array_push(created_array, array($SKU, $product_qty)). Hope it helps.

```
$items = $order->get_items();
$push = array();
// Output the loop
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
// Getting some information
  $product_qty = $item['qty'];
  $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
  $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);

  // SKU
  $SKU = $product->get_sku();

  array_push($push, array('sku'=>$SKU, 'qty'=>$product_qty));
  print_r($SKU); 
  print_r($product_qty); 
  print_r('&nbsp;');
}
// this gives all 3 quantities and all 3 sku, added a space at the end for easier reading

// this only gives the 1st entry of both variables but i need all 3 of both variables

$link = '<a href="https://www.domainname.someurl';
for ($i=0;$i<count($push);$i++){
        $link .= $push[$i]['qty'];
        $link .= $push[$i]['sku'];
    }
    $link .= '" target=_blank>';
 echo $link;
```

Comment: sadly : Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback
thanks thou for your help, much appreciated :)

Comment: worked a bit around it, just this left :) "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the warning from what i suggested and not somewhere else?

Comment: Ok so to access the array values you need to do it like this $push[index][key_name]. If you know how many items there are in the array you can just hardcode them, if it can vary then use a loop and format it as you need. Let me know how you need the end string to be and i'll do it for you and provide an explanation

Comment: yea sorry used echo instead of print_p or something like that , anyway added the $push to the hyperlink and got "Array" as end result, and sorry but i dont get what you mean with how i need the end string to be?

Comment: Echo and print_r are different functions. Anyway, do you need to have all the sku values and qty in the link you want to echo? Like www.randomurl.com/firstSKU-firstQTY-secondSKU-secondQTY? What exactly are you trying to do with the values of SKU and product_qty ?

Comment: exactly , sku gives f.e. a-b-c-d while qty gives 1-2-3-4, i worked on olibiaz's codes and got a-b-c-d 1-2-3-4, now just adjust to get firstSKU-firstQTY-secondSKU-secondQTY.

Comment: i edited above, that will add all the sku values and the qty to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$items = $order->get_items();
// Output the loop
$product_qty_string = '';
$sku_string = '';
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    // Getting some information
    $product_qty_string .= $item['qty']."-";
    // SKU
    $SKU = $product->get_sku();
    $sku_string .=$SKU."-";
}

$product_quantity = rtrim($product_qty_string,'-');
$SKU = rtrim($sku_string,'-');
echo '<a href="https://www.domainname.someurl'.$product_quantity.''.$SKU.''" target=_blank>';

echo "<p>TEXT</p></a>";
```

Comment: there is $$SKU, it should be $SKU = rtrim($sku_string,'-')

Comment: yea noticed that. corrected it in my code, sadly not working but thank you for trying :)

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add your values in a array and then implode them.

```
$items = $order->get_items();

// Output the loop
$SKU = $product_qty = [];
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    // Getting some information
    $product_qty[] = $item['qty'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);

    // SKU
    $SKU[] = $product->get_sku();
    print_r($SKU); 
    print_r($product_qty); 
    print_r('&nbsp;');
}
$sku_string = implode('-', $SKU);
$product_qty_string = implode('-', $product_qty);

echo '<a href="https://www.domainname.someurl'.$product_qty_string .$sku_string . '" target=_blank>'; 

echo "<p>TEXT</p></a>";
```

You can implode your data with any separator you want, i use "-" for my example but its depending on your needs.

Comment: thats why : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line "$SKU = $product_qty = [];" i tryed the array and with join and implode

Comment: which version of php do you have? try
    $SKU = array();
    $product_qty = array();

Comment: This is great now,thank you very much, i just need to "fuse" the $sku_string and $product_qty_string because now i get a-b-c-d 1-2-3-4, but i actually need a-1 b-2 c-3 d-4